# Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, error-handling

Hello I'm currently getting the common error of 
"Domino.java:32: error: non-static method getValue() cannot be referenced from a static context"
I kind of understand that this is a problem because its only an instance of the getValue method. In this compareTo method I'm trying to pass in some domino and compare it to the set domino and return a -1,0,1 depending on some comparisons. I need the sum of both sides of the domino to compare them which is why I was trying to get domino.getValue(), at this point i'm just not sure how to implement this. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated

```
public class Domino {
    public static int side1;
    public static int side2;

       public Domino(int aside, int bside){
           side1 = aside;
           side2 = bside ;
       }
       public Domino() {
           side1 = 4;
           side2 = 5;
       }

       public boolean isDouble(){
           if(side1 == side2) {
               return true;
           }
           else {
               return false;
           }
       }
       public int getValue(){
          return side1 + side2;
       }
       public int compareTo(Domino someDomino)
         {
            int count = 0;
            if(Domino.getValue() < someDomino.getValue()){
               count = -1; 
             }if(Domino.getValue() > someDomino.getValue()){
                   count = 1; 
                 }
             if(Domino.getValue() == someDomino.getValue()){
                   count = -0; 
                 }
           return count;  
         }

       public static void main(String args[]) {

       }

}
```

Comment: Aside from the question you are asking about the compareTo(...) method, this will fail because you are storing the values for each side as static variables instead of instance variables. When you create the second Domino it will overwrite the values that the first one stored - they will all have the same value.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are calling the methods statically on the Domino class inside your compareTo method. Get rid of the `Domino.` part of your calls to getValue().

```
public int compareTo(Domino someDomino)
         {
            int count = 0;
            if(getValue() < someDomino.getValue()){
               count = -1; 
             }if(getValue() > someDomino.getValue()){
                   count = 1; 
                 }
             if(getValue() == someDomino.getValue()){
                   count = -0; 
                 }
           return count;  
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Domino` is the class itself, you need to compare the object in parameter (*explicit parameter*) with the current instance (*implicit parameter*), the one on which you're calling the method, it's `this`

```
public int compareTo(Domino someDomino){
    int count = 0;
    if(this.getValue() < someDomino.getValue()){
        count = -1; 
    }else if(this.getValue() > someDomino.getValue()){
        count = 1; 
    }
    return count;  
}
```

This is same :

```
public int compareTo(Domino someDomino) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getValue(), someDomino.getValue());
}
```

Also :

- use `else if` because your tests cannot be both true
- no need to check for `equality` at the end, if it is not `<` and not `>` so it's `==` and count will be already `equals` to `0`
- **IMPORTANT** `public static int side1;` =>  `public int side1;` if they are static they will be same for **EACH** Domino

---

It would a good practice to add Comparable interface, to allow sorting of the Dominos in a list for ex, the method `compareTo()` will be used automatically

```
public class Domino implements Comparable<Domino>{...}
```

Comment: As the class is written, this will always return 0 because the Domino instances store the values as class variables. Should be fine if side1 and side2 are non-static.

Comment: @JonathanS i've edited just a minute before you comment ;)